# len of array always 2

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
int *a[4] = {
    (int[]){ 1},
    (int[]){ -4, -5},
    (int[]){ -4, -5, 0},
    (int[]){ 1, 3, 4, 6}
};

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    len = sizeof(a[i])/sizeof(int);
```

I know it is not a correct approach, but len is always 2. Could someone explain why len is two? Is it a undefined behavior, if not, how is it being calculated?

Comment: There if no multidimensional array in your code.

Comment: yeah, array of pointer it is. I flagged the question myself to delete.

Comment: You don't need to flag the question yourself to be deleted, instead, you have the option to actually delete it, because you are the author of the question.

Comment: If the question has a answer you cannot delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[i]` is pointer to `int`. `sizeof(a[i])` will return sizeof `int *`, not the array it points to. On 64-bit machines, size of a pointer is `8` bytes and size of `int` is `4` bytes. `8/4 = 2`.

Comment: oh, ya. was simple one. I do not why it messed my head. Thanks anyways.